# Visualizar Imágenes de una carpeta con nombre desconocido

Tags: android-studio, imagen

estoy haciendo una aplicación en Android Studio y necesitaría visualizar imágenes de una carpeta, dichas imágenes no se el nombre ya que las va introduciendo el usuario y se van guardando con el nombre que el usuario quiere, la ruta de la carpeta si la sé pero no el nombre las imágenes a visualizar. Mi pregunta es ¿Hay alguna forma de visualizar todas las imágenes de dicha carpeta, sin conocer el nombre de las mismas? Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

---

[image: Esta es la carpeta de donde quiero recuperar las imagenes]

Y este es el .xml donde quiero ponerlo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="@style/pantalla_secundaria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/oculta1"
            style="@style/casilla"
            android:contentDescription="@string/casilla"
            android:onClick="oculta1"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOculta1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oculta1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/personalizar"
            android:textColorHint="#7B1FA2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oculta1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/oculta12"
            style="@style/casilla"
            android:layout_marginStart="377dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="372dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oculta1"
            android:contentDescription="@string/casilla"
            android:onClick="oculta12"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/oculta1"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOculta12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oculta12"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/personalizar"
            android:textColorHint="#303F9F"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textOculta1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oculta13"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/oculta13"
            style="@style/casilla"
            android:layout_marginStart="377dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="382dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oculta12"
            android:contentDescription="@string/casilla"
            android:onClick="oculta13"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/oculta12"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOculta13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oculta13"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="260dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/personalizar"
            android:textColorHint="#303F9F"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textOculta12"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oculta13"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/oculta14"
            style="@style/casilla"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="260dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oculta13"
            android:contentDescription="@string/casilla"
            android:onClick="oculta14"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/oculta13"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOculta14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oculta14"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="380dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/personalizar"
            android:textColorHint="#303F9F"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textOculta13"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oculta14"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/oculta15"
            style="@style/casilla"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/oculta14"
            android:contentDescription="@string/casilla"
            android:onClick="oculta15"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/oculta14"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textOculta15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/oculta15"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="495dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="@string/personalizar"
            android:textColorHint="#303F9F"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textOculta14"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/oculta15"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.005" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Hola, recuerda adjuntar código que lo has hecho o cerrarán tu pregunta

Comment: ¿Cuál es el lenguaje?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualmente solo se puede obtener información dentro de la estructura de la aplicación, dentro de su directorio "`files`". Por ejemplo, si el `package name` de mi aplicación es `com.jorgesys.kotlin1`, podré acceder a este directorio, en el cual se deben guardar los archivos.

```
/data/user/0/com.jorgesys.kotlin1/files
```

Puedo obtener el directorio de esta forma:

```
    Log.i("File", "Internal directory:: $filesDir")
```

salida:

```
/data/user/0/com.jorgesys.kotlin1/files
```

y obtener sus archivos de esta forma:

```
File(filesDir.path).walk().forEach { //obtiene sus archivos.
    Log.i("File", "archivo:: $it")
}
```

salida:

```
archivo:: /data/user/0/com.jorgesys.kotlin1/files/Ioana 2022-11-14 at 12.25.03 PM.jpeg
archivo:: /data/user/0/com.jorgesys.kotlin1/files/Ioana Image 2022-11-14 at 12.25.03 PM.jpeg
archivo:: /data/user/0/com.jorgesys.kotlin1/files/Ioana 2022-11-08 at 11.53.22 AM.jpeg
archivo:: /data/user/0/com.jorgesys.kotlin1/files/Ioana 2022-11-07 at 1.46.21 PM.jpeg
archivo:: /data/user/0/com.jorgesys.kotlin1/files/Ioana 2022-11-14 at 5.25.27 PM.jpeg
```

Comment: Gracias Jorgeys eso me sirve. Un saludo